# Offer or push menu to ssh users

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I want to present any user that logs into my debian unit via ssh a menu automatically. Currently they must log in and run the menu.sh script manually on the command line. Can this be done?

Comment: run it in `.bashrc`, `.profile` or similar (many similar questions around here). But it will break apps like `scp`, `sftp`, `rsync`, so make sure you really want to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can edit `/etc/profile` (system-wide) or `~user/.profile` (per-user, all bourne shells) or `~user/.bash_profile` (per-user, bash-specific) or a similar script to call the menu.

If you *only* want to show it to users who log in through SSH, check if the `SSH_CLIENT` environment variable has been set:

```
if [ ! -z "$SSH_CLIENT" ]; then
    menu.sh
fi
```

otherwise it will be used for *every* login. Also, you should *not* place this in a `.bashrc` file; the difference between `.bashrc` on the one hand and `.profile` or `.bash_profile` is that the former is run for *every* shell that is started, whereas the latter is only started for *login* shells.

Answer (score 3):

This is an alternative to @Wouter's answer.

Most *nix boxes have a file where user data is stored on, like "/etc/passwd". This file stores several information regarding to the user account, one of them is the "shell" that will run if the user correctly send the login/password. The following example shows when the user log into the system, bash will run:

`slave:x:0:0:Linux Slave User,,,:/home/user:/bin/bash`

In this way, you can change the last part to whatever you want to run.

So what's the difference from the previous answers? 
- In most Linux boxes this answer is more secure than the previous.

This method will run directly the program/script you want, and - if the script or program breaks (a bug for instance), the user gets immediately logged-off - because the user is attached to that process.

The previous answer will attach the user to the bash (or another shell), if the running script is finished, the user will go directly to the bash prompt and can run any command on Linux.

In other words, if you are running a menu that is supposed to be the only method you want users interact with your Linux, make sure your menu never finishes or breaks. If there's a chance of having a bug on your menu, use the option of this answer instead.

You don't have to manually edit `/etc/password,` use the following command instead (as super user):

`chsh -s "your program" "login"`