# Limit shell access for SSH user to telnet only

Tags: shell, centos, security

We have a CentOS 7 server running an application that uses telnet.
Instead of opening up the port to allow direct telnet acccess we'd like a more secure option of users using SSH to login and connect to telnet from there.

However, these users don't need access to anything else, at all. Thus I was wondering if it is possible to either create a custom shell that automatically opens up the telnet interface, or to limit a shell to only allow the telnet command.

Ofcourse if there are other, better, solutions available I'd love to hear about those too!

The specific command they'd need access to is:

```
telnet <ip> 25568
```

whereas `<ip>` would be one of the few local ip adresses configured

Comment: Are the users connecting with password or public key auth? Public key auth can force a specific command to be run.

Comment: using a password, not all users have the technical knowledge to use public keys unfortunately, thus for simplicity we've opted to use a username/password combination. Of course there is also the point that the IP parameter differs from time to time, running a single command wouldn't work in that case.

Comment: Sure, look at the `chsh` command.

Comment: Running a menu as their login shell that offers the choice of what to `exec telnet ...` to would be a likely option.

Comment: @thrig that sounds like a perfect solution, how would I go about configuring that?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/185843/menu-script-over-ssh has sample code and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250230/offer-or-push-menu-to-ssh-users shows two ways to present it

Comment: Could you add that as an answer to this post? It sounds like you've provided me with what I needed :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method would be to [`chsh` their account](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chsh) to use something like the following as their login shell, which loops forever until an appropriate number is input, at which point the script replaces itself with the `telnet` call. You may want to disable the `telnet` escape code (`telnet -E ...`) if the commands offered there are problematical, and otherwise have a look at each option `telnet` offers to see if any of those should or should not be set. It may also be prudent to `unset` or specifically set certain environment variables carried along from the remote SSH client (e.g. `PATH`, locale settings, etc; inspect these with `env > whatenvisset` or such from the script).

```
#!/bin/bash

PS3='number for remote host: '

while :; do
  select ipaddr in 192.0.2.4 192.0.2.5 192.0.2.6; do
    if [[ -n "$ipaddr" ]]; then
        exec /usr/bin/telnet "$ipaddr" 25568
    fi
  done
done
```

This would be easy to automate remotely if necessary via `expect` though perhaps less pretty than using `dialog` to throw up a more graphical menu of options.